# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void getSUM()
{
    // SQL query that gets total of product sales where category id = 1
    string SqlQuery = @"SELECT Price AS TotalSales 
  FROM STOCK
  WHERE Barcode = '" + TextBox1 + "'";

    // Declare and open a connection to database


    sqlcon.Open();

    // Creates SqlCommand object
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, sqlcon);

    // Gets total sales
    decimal TotalSales = Convert.ToDecimal(comm.ExecuteScalar());

    // Close connection
    sqlcon.Close();

    // Adds formatted output to GridView footer
    GridView1.Columns[3].FooterText = String.Format("{0:c}", TotalSales);
}
```

i just want to add the price at the footer of the gridview. i don't understand what's wrong. the error is in this line GridView1.Columns[3].FooterText = String.Format("{0:c}", TotalSales);

Comment: Do you have 4 columns? If not, you'll get that error when you try and access the 4th column (index 3).

Comment: Does `GridView1` have 4 columns?  `[]` index accessors are zero based. so when you put 3 in there, you're trying to access the 4th column

Comment: Check how many columns are there in Gridview. This error shows up when your trying to use an non-existing-index to get the column.

Comment: i have 4 columns. and i want to access the 4th one

Comment: Check `GridView1.Columns.Count`. It will give you less then 3, thats why you got that error.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd **strongly** urge you to stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: i'll check that @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` in your GridView. When using this you will only have access to the columns in the `RowCreated` and `RowDataBound` events. When the grid is done building the column count will be 0.

Better use TemplateFields. You'll have much more control that way.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("myColumn") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now `GridView1.Columns.Count` will return `1`.